# Regular Expression to match with exclusion of some pattern

Tags: javascript, regex

I have a text

`<1.1.1>This is para one with <1.1.2>more than five words. I <1.1.3>is trying to test grammar <1.1.4>API with this. <1.2.1>This are para two, let's <1.2.2>test it. I am using <1.2.3>it <1.3.1>​`

In this I want to match 

 `is para one with more than five words. I is trying to test grammar API with this. T`

I have tried one reg ex

`(?:(\<([0-9]*\.[0-9]*\.[0-9]*)\>))(This is para one with more)`

I want in result as below :

 `is para one with <1.1.2>more than five words. I <1.1.3>is trying to test grammar <1.1.4>API with this. <1.2.1>T`

but not able to find solution, how I can match exclude word recursively.

Comment: Could you explicitly define the pattern you want to extract? 
Since you commented *"Thank you. But I don't want to replace pattern <1.1.1> .... I want that too in matched result"*

Comment: I have added expected result

Answer (score 3):

You can do

```js
let str = "<1.1.1>This is para one with <1.1.2>more than five words. I <1.1.3>is trying to test grammar <1.1.4>API with this. <1.2.1>This are para two, let's <1.2.2>test it. I am using <1.2.3>it <1.3.1>​";

str = str.replace(/<\d\.\d\.\d>/g, '');

console.log(str);
```

Comment: Thank you. But I don't want to replace pattern <1.1.1> .... I want that too in matched result

Comment: In result I want ```is para one with <1.1.2>more than five words. I <1.1.3>is trying to test grammar <1.1.4>API with this. <1.2.1>T```

Comment: is there any pattern ? like length of string or match till a specific occurrence

Comment: there is no pattern. Only we need to match our text against text with delimiter like <n.n.n>